# Querying into JSON in PostgreSQL without using a subquery

Tags: postgresql

I'm interested in creating a query of a raw json blob without having to use a subquery in PostgreSQL. The query looks like this:

```sql
 SELECT id, 
    ((db_bench_results.result::json -> 'Runner'::text)) as runner
   FROM public.db_bench_results as full_results 
   WHERE ((db_bench_results.result::json -> 'Runner'::text)) = "this_runner";
```

However, when I do this, I get:

```
ERROR:  column "this_runner" does not exist
LINE 11: ...E ((db_bench_results.result::json -> 'Runner'::text)) = "this_runner";
```

Is this possible without creating a subquery and joining the tables together?

Comment: text in postgres uses single quotes `'`, double quotes `"` are reserved for named fields, so just change the condition to `= 'this_runner'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String constants have to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. The double quotes are for identifiers.

As you want to compare a value as `text`, use the `->>` operator to make the returned value a `text` not a `jsonb` (or `json`) value.

So the following should work:

```
SELECT id, 
       db_bench_results.result ->> 'Runner' as runner
FROM public.db_bench_results as full_results 
WHERE db_bench_results.result ->> 'Runner' = 'this_runner';
```

This assumes that `results` is a `jsonb` (which it should be) or `json` column.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this, is this efficient?

```sql
 SELECT f.runner from (select ((db_bench_results.result -> 'Runner'::text))::text AS runner,
   FROM public.db_bench_results) as f where f.runner like '%this_runner%'
```